# How to set zoom levels in chrome browser using watir webdriver(ruby watir- set specific zoom level / zoom out /zoom in)

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I didn't get to know how to set the browser capabilities in watir, so got this online and tried  the following but it didn't work for me.

My problem is, i was suppose to reduce the zoom level to 75% and do the rest of the coding:

```
driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
driver.send_keys [:control, :subtract]*3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common notion that when people use selenium,they tend to use `driver` variable, but when people use WATIR they use `browser`, so use browser instead of driver.

And to answer your question, you can use the following code to set up your zoom level.

```
browser=Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='75%'")
```